# newly created UIViewController is not available in a storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboard, xcode4.6

I'm running into an issue with one of my view controllers and am hoping someone can help me out: **my storyboard behaves as if the view controller does not exist**, preventing me from making connections to the controller.

I've created a custom freeform view controller in a storyboard, it's purpose is to be displayed in a popover, allowing a user to edit a `UITextLabel` using the popover's `UITextView`.

I'm dynamically instantiating the view controller for the popover using the code below:

```
//create a popover with a text view under a label to be edited,
// allowing the user to edit the label with the popover

                GLAppDelegate* appDelegate = (GLAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                UIViewController *mvc = (UIViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
                PopoverTextViewController* textViewController = [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popoverTextViewController"];
                textViewController.textView.text = ((OutlinedLabel*)v.attributedView).text;
                textViewController.label = (OutlinedLabel*)v.attributedView;

                [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
                self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:textViewController];

                [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:v.attributedView.frame inView:v permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

It appears to me that the view controller I made is a typical view controller:

[image]

**The problem that I'm running in is that autocomplete behaves as if there is no such view controller available in my app.** Even if I manually paste it's name here, I cannot connect the textView property from the storyboard to the view controler.

[image]

When I test the code, it works - the label can be edited with the popover, but I cannot set the text within the popover, because I cannot link the text view to the view controller.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I just created a fresh project in Xcode 4.6.1 (4H512) and made a new UIViewController subclass. The class was available in IB right after it was created. Maybe your class doesn't match your controller type, eg. it's a UITableViewController in IB and you try to make it a  UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, it is a composite, 3 piece thing.

1. I did a "**clean**" on the project, then quit xCode and restarted it - this clears some weird bugs, and did work in this case. I was able to add the controller in storyboard
2. I forgot `IBOutlet` next to textview: `@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextView* textView;`
3. In case of popover, the **textView property is nil, until viewDidLoad gets called** after the popover is presented, so the code had to be reworked as follows:

   ```
   //create a popover under the label with a text view, allowing the user to edit the label with the popover
   GLAppDelegate* appDelegate = (GLAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   UIViewController *mvc = (UIViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
   PopoverTextViewController* textViewController = [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popoverTextViewController"];


   [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:textViewController];

   //before this call, all views of the controller are not loaded
   [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:v.attributedView.frame inView:v permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

   //once popover is presented, the textView is created and is available
   textViewController.textView.text = ((OutlinedLabel*)v.attributedView).text;
   textViewController.label = (OutlinedLabel*)v.attributedView;
   ```

I hope someone finds this useful.